# Change from HTML character references to utf-8 in a bash script ie. &#257; becomes ā

Tags: bash, utf-8, character-encoding

How would you go about translating a document that contains the following character references to their actual readable characters in a bash script?

```
&#257; &#225; &#462; &#224; &#275; &#233; &#283; &#232; &#299; &#237; &#464; &#236; &#470; &#472; &#474; &#476; &#252; &#470; &#472; &#474; &#476; &#252;
```

These change in order to ā á ǎ à ē é ě è ī í ǐ ì ǖ ǘ ǚ ǜ ü ǖ ǘ ǚ ǜ ü

Comment: stackoverflow allows HTML entities. Might want to edit that.

Comment: My first response is to use sed, if it's just those entities. Direct replacement should be possible that way.
If you want it to work for arbitrary entities, though, then I can't think of anything offhand (I'm not a major sh person, sadly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to Perl then it's relatively simple:

```
perl -ne 'binmode STDOUT,":utf8";s/&#([0-9]*);/pack("U",$1)/eg;print' \
  document.html
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
html2utf8() {
  perl -ne 'binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; s/&#([0-9]*);/pack("U",$1)/eg; print'
}
echo 'testing 1 &#257; 2 &#300; 3 &#275;' | html2utf8
```

Produces:

```
testing 1 ā 2 Ĭ 3 ē
```

Comment: Yep I've got access to perl so is probably the easiest and neatest way to do it. Honestly The whole project would be best scipted in pearl anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a bash only way of doing this, it looks like there are some solutions in this thread: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-820377-view-previous.html?sid=b35246f20410ba95ee048970d01ac6b3